# tf.keras manual device placement

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

Migrating to the TF2.0 I'm trying to use the `tf.keras` approach for solving things.
In standard TF, I can use `with tf.device(...)` to control where ops are.

For example, I might have a model something like

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Input(..),
                             tf.keras.layers.Embedding(...),
                             tf.keras.layers.LSTM(...),
                             ...])
```

Assuming I want to have the network up until `Embedding` (including) on the CPU and the and from there on on the GPU, how will I go about that?
(This is just an example, the layers could have nothing to do with embeddings)

If the solution involves subclassing `tf.keras.Model` that is OK too, I don't mind not using `Sequential`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Keras functional API:

```py
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(..)
with tf.device("/GPU:0"):
    model = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(...)(inputs)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(...)(model)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```